# Kendo tooltip category incorrect

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am having a strange problem with the tooltip in a KendoStock Chart. Depending on how many days i have displaying and how much of the total amount of data I am focusing on in the navigator I will receive a Date (category) that is incorrect for the series value being shown.
The date will change slightly in the tooltip as I move the navigator. It has shown up to 10 days off from the correct date if I lookup the date it should show for a specific value in the data source. Is there a way i can ensure the date (category) in the tool tip will always be the date associated with that specif value from the data source?

I have tried using both "category" and "dataItem.Date" in the tooltip template but both give me the same result.

```
$("#MainLineChart").kendoStockChart({
                    dataSource: {                            
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "/MainApi/Action",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                                return JSON.stringify({ data: { START: Date.parse($("#Start").val()), END: Date.parse($("#End").val()) } });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dateField: "Date",
                    valueAxis: { labels: { format: "{0}" } },
                    series: [
                      { name: "Series 1", type: "@chartvalue", field: "SERIES1"},
                      { name: "Series 2", type: "@chartvalue", field: "SERIES2"},
                      { name: "Series 3", type: "@chartvalue", field: "SERIES3"},
                      { name: "Series 4", type: "@chartvalue", field: "SERIES4"}
                    ],
                    categoryAxis: {
                        baseUnit: "days",
                        baseUnitStep: "auto",
                        maxDateGroups: 30,
                        labels: { rotation: "auto", dateFormats: { days: "M / d / yyyy" } }
                    },
                    navigator: {
                        series: [{ type: "line", field: "SERIES1"}, { type: "line", field: "SERIES2"}, { type: "line", field: "SERIES3"}, { type: "line", field: "SERIES4"}],
                        categoryAxis: {
                            baseUnit: "months",
                            baseUnitStep: "auto"
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        template: "#= series.name #: #= addCommas(value) # <br/> #= kendo.format(\'{0:D}\', category)  #"
                    },
                    dragEnd: navigate,
                    zoomEnd: navigate,
                    selectEnd: navigate
                });
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Ok, I have added my code for the chart